# Unit Testing Google Cloud Datastore using Cloud Datastore Client library

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-flexible

I'm developing a Java application in the App Engine Flexible environment that requires access to Datastore. I've had no trouble setting this up, however when it comes to unit testing I am unable to test any of the Datastore code (without an external connection to Google Cloud, which would be an integration test).

I am using the [Cloud Datastore client library](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) to connect to Datastore, which doesn't appear to work with the `LocalServiceTestHelper` as indicated [in this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting#datastore-memcache).

The client library I'm using is in the `com.google.cloud` package, whereas the unit testing tools are in `com.google.appengine`, so they are incompatible. Is there a way to use the `LocalServiceTestHelper` with the `com.google.cloud` libraries (or an alternate in-memory datastore for testing)?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong GAE (Google App Engine) unit testing tools are only for GAE standard.

From my point of view you have 2 options:

- Use GAE standard and follow this guide [[1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting)].
- Use GAE flexible with JUnit and Datastore emulator [[2](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator)].